# Sending a parameter with space to another script in bash

Tags: bash, variables, scripting

I need to send a variable to another script (BASH) and uset after in this first script. The code goes something like this:

```
read var
source myscipt.sh $var
echo $var
```

The problem is that if y put spaces when entering $var after sending it to myscript.sh I only have the first one.

NOTE: In myscript.sh I only use $1 does this have something to do with the problem?

Thanx!!!

Comment: Does myscipt.sh set `var`? When you `source` it, it runs in the same shell, and hence will modify the variables of the "parent" script. This is one of the reasons you should generally run scripts with `./myscript.sh` rather than `source`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use quotes. Thus var will be considered as only one parameter, even if it contains spaces.

```
source myscipt.sh "$var"
```

Comment: But I dont really care how many parameters myscipt.sh recieves, I want to know why after that it only have one!

Comment: without seeing your script I only can guess that it manages $1 only (not $2, $3,...)

Comment: Stephane... yes indeed, in myscript.sh I only use $1 but does this affect my main script? I am not changing the variables...

Comment: please ask an other question and give code samples to show the difficulty you meet